# Как спроектировать базу данных?

Tags: база-данных, laravel

**Route**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\YarnController;

Route::get('/yarn/{slug}', [YarnController::class, 'show'])->name('yarn.show');
```

**YarnController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Yarn;

class YarnController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        return view('yarn.show', [
            'yarns' => Yarn::where('slug', $slug)->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Условием выборки является `slug`. Если в базе есть товары (пряжа) с таким `slug`, то мы показываем их пользователю.

**Хочу реализовать:**

У товара (пряжи) есть связанные модели. `Country`, `Manufacturer`, `Fiber` и т.д. Они имеют свой `slug`. Неплохо бы включить их в условие выборки.

```
/yarn/alize (Manufacturer)
/yarn/acrylic (Fiber)
/yarn/alize-lana-gold (Yarn)
```

Есть идея хранить все `slug` в одной таблице. При выборки товаров (пряжи) проверять, есть там такой `slug` или нет.

Просто пример. Наверное это так работать не будет.

```
Yarn::whereHas('table', function($query) use ($slug) {
    $query->where('slug', $slug);
})->get();
```

Трудность еще в том, что `Country` и `Manufacturer` имеет отношение один ко многим, а `Fiber` многие ко многим.

Не понятно, как при добавлении новой страны (например) записать все данные страны в таблицу `Country`, а слоган в таблицу `Slug`.

Любые идеи как реализовать?

Comment: Не понятно `Неплохо бы включить их в условие выборки` - в качестве параметра query, или как slug? И если slug, как это должно быть `/yarn/slug_1/slug_2/slug_3` или slug на одном уровне, и скрипт сам должен искать либо по производиелю, либо по стране, ...

Comment: `Не понятно, как при добавлении новой страны (например) записать все данные страны в таблицу Country, а слоган в таблицу Slug` - через observer, он же [наблюдатель](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers)

Comment: @TotalPusher Хотелось бы сделать на одном уровне без вложениях параметров. Slug всегда уникальный.  То есть, просто показываем данные в зависимости от slug. Вот только как это все связать. В любом случае буду признателен любому варианту.

Comment: Я бы сделал так. 1) Создал наблюдателя, который следил бы за всеми 4 моделями - Country, Manufacturer, Fiber и собственно товаром. В нем - действия created/updated/deleted, которые пишут в таблицу Slug следующее: название модели (Country, Manufacturer, Fiber, товар) на котором сейчас сработал наблюдатель, id в этой модели, slug. 2) Через уникальный индекс и валидацию запроса можно сделать гарантировано уникальный slug 3) В контроллер приходит slug, по нему отыскивается запись в таблице Slug. А у всех моделей я бы завел отношение "товар" yard(){}: BelongsToMany, и таким способом получить товары

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант #1**

Вам нужен обычный фильтр. Передавайте условия через `GET` и в зависимости от того какие данные присутствуют, стройте нужный запрос.

**URL**

```
site.test/yarn?country[]=1&country[]=2&manufacture[]=5&manufacture[]=1&fibers[]=4
```

Простой пример. Можете заменить `id` на `slug`;

```
Route::get('yarn', static function (Request $request) {
    $builder = (new \App\Models\Product())->newModelQuery();

    if ($request->has('country')) {
        $builder->country($request->get('country'));
    }

    if ($request->has('manufacture')) {
        $builder->whereHas('manufacture', function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereIn('id', $request->get('manufacture'));
        });
    }

    if ($request->has('fibers')) {
        $builder->whereHas('fibers', function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereIn('id', $request->get('fibers'));
        });
    }

   $products = $builder->get();
});
```

`whereHas` можно заменить на [Dynamic Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#dynamic-scopes).

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function scopeCountry($builder, $ids)
    {
        return $builder->whereHas('country', function ($q) use ($ids) {
            $q->whereIn('id', $ids);
        });
    }
}
```

**Вариант #2**

Вы можете использовать не обязательные параметры роутера.

Если предположить, что потребуется выборка только по **manufacture** или **fibers**.
Я бы в таком случае заменил название аргументов на `$first` и тд. А к **slug** перед сохранением добавлял префикс (**ctr**-ukraine, **mfc**-factory). Это позволит быстро уточнить к какому отношению относится параметр, составить правильный запрос и не привязываться к жёсткой структуре **slug**.

```
Route::get(
    '/yarn/{country?}/{manufacture?}/{fiber?}',
    static function (
        $country = null,
        $manufacture = null,
        $fiber = null
    ) {
    $builder = (new \App\Models\Product())->newModelQuery();

    if (! is_null($country)) {
        $builder->whereHas('country', function ($q) use ($country) {
            $q->where('id', $country);
        });
    }

    // . . .

   $products = $builder->get();
});
```

Comment: @E-K Вы написали отличный ответ, но не под мою задачу. Находил пакеты для фильтров, да и примеров в интернете немало. Мне требуется ЧПУ. То есть, когда производитель, страна и т.д явно указан в URL. У меня для каждого производителя, страны и т.д есть описание. Мне нужно показать это описание в зависимости от URL и вывести все товары связные с этим производителем, страной и т.д. Условие, когда мы показываем "И" или "ИЛИ" — мне не нужно т.к описание у нас одно и оно либо производителя, либо страны и т.д.

Comment: @РодионПоляков Вы хотите что бы **slug** содержал все 3 варианта? К примеру, `./yarn/usa/tech/blue`.

Answer (score 0):

Хранить все `slug` в одном месте - плохая идея. У вас получится нездоровая структура БД.

Используйте sql, это поможет вам делать с вашей базой данных всё что угодно, orm вас сильно ограничивает.

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите получить все товары где `slug` равен введённой строке, а так же товары, где slug у связанных моделей равен введённой строке.

Я не знаю какая именно у вас база данных, но это решение будет работать для большинства:

```
WITH
    slug AS (
        SELECT 'you_slug' AS slug
    ),
    suitable_products AS ( -- сюда попадут все id товаров, у которых связанные модели подходят под введённую строку
        SELECT yarn_id FROM country WHERE slug=(SELECT slug FROM slug)
        UNION
        SELECT yarn_id FROM manufacturer WHERE slug=(SELECT slug FROM slug)
        UNION
        SELECT yarn_id
            FROM yarns_to_fibers ytf -- yarns_to_fibers - ваша таблица, где хранится many_to_many для продуктов и волокон
                INNER JOIN fiber f ON f.id = ytf.fiber_id AND f.slug=(SELECT slug FROM slug) 
    )


-- yarn - таблица, где хранятся ваши товары
SELECT y.*
FROM yarn y
WHERE y.id IN (
    suitable_products.yarn_id
) OR y.slug=(SELECT slug FROM slug)
LIMIT 20;
```

!! Название таблиц и столбцов могут отличаться от ваших. Сверьте с вашей БД

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

Ищем первый найденный объект любой из 4 моделей, отправляем его во вьюху, иначе возвращаем 404.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Yarn;
use App\Models\Country;
use App\Models\Manufacture;
use App\Models\Fiber;

class YarnController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $models = [Yarn::class, Country::class, Manufacture::class, Fiber::class];

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $item = $model::where('slug', slug)->first();
            if ($item) {
                if (method_exists($item, 'yarns')) {
                    $item->load(['yarns.childrenRelation', 'yarns.childrenRelation2']);
                } else {
                    $item->load(['childrenRelation', 'childrenRelation2']);
                }

                return view('yarn.show', compact('item'));
            }
        }

        abort(404);
    }
}
```

Это из расчёта, что у `Yarn` уникальный url. Вы почему-то делаете на `->first()`, а `get()`, что навело на мысли, что url может быть не уникальным.

**View:**

Здесь обращаемся к релейшену `yarns`, который должен быть настроен внутри моделей Manufacture, Country, Fiber.

```
@if ($item->yarns)
    $item - экземпляр модели Fiber, Manufacture или Country.
    @foreach ($item->yarns)
        тут идут ярны у трёх моделей
    @endforeach
@else 
    $item - экземпляр модели Yarn
@endif
```

Скорее всего во вьюхе надо будет определять, что за модель содержится в `$item`, тогда у нас есть множество приёмов:

```
$item->getTable() === 'fibers'
$item->getMorphClass() === '\App\Models\Manufacture'
$item instanceof \App\Models\Country
is_a($this, \App\Models\Yarn::class)
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Смущает только 4 запроса к базе. Но я так понимаю, тут как не пиши все равно будет 4 запроса.

Comment: Как применить жадную загрузку в вашем примере? Мы получаем товары оплетённого Manufacture, Country или Fiber и к этим же товарам нужно вернуть данные.

Comment: @РодионПоляков там максимум 4 запроса, но может быть и меньше, если встретили модель на 1 или 2 итерации цикла.

Comment: @РодионПоляков можете использовать метод модели `load()`, работает, как `with()` query builder'а, только применяется уже к коллекции и модели и может быть использован вне постройки запроса. Надеюсь правильно понял вопрос.