# Можно ли пересобрать коллекцию?

Tags: laravel

Есть модель Category и модель Product. Между этими моделями связь многие-ко-многим. На странице категории мы получаем все товары этой категории и к каждому товару все его категории.

Пример.

```
$category->type
$category->name

@foreach ($category->products as $product)
    $product->name

    @foreach ($product->categories as $category)
        $category->type
        $category->name
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

На выходе получаем.

```
Manufacturer
Alize

    Alize Lana Gold

       Manufacturer
       Alize
       Country
       Turkey
       Fiber
       Acrylic
```

Каждая категория имеет свой тип. Например: Country, Manufacturer или Fiber. Категория страны, производителя или состава. Country и Manufacturer у товара всегда один, а вот Fiber может быть много.

Можно ли как-то пересобрать (не знаю как правильно сказать) коллекцию, чтобы товар возвращался со всеми категория, к которым он принадлежит?

То есть, чтобы можно было сделать так.

```
$category->type
$category->name

@foreach ($category->products as $product)
    $product->country // категория
    $product->manufacturer // категория
    $product->name

    @foreach ($product->fibers  as $fiber) // категория
        $fiber->name
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Мы явно пишем Country, Manufacturer и только Fiber перебираем в массиве т.к у товара может быть много категорий этого типа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, Вы явно что-то странное делаете, если Country, Manufacturer и Fiber это некие категории, которые belongsToMany, которые зачастую нужны вам как belongsTo, не проще сделать их отдельными моделями?

Теперь по существу. Я вижу для вас 2 варианта.

**1 вариант: Getters в модели Product**

Просто добавляем геттерсы в модель, которые будут искать внутри коллекций наших отношений.

```
public function getCountryAttribute()
{
    return $this->categories->firstWhere('type', 'country');
}

public function getManufacturerAttribute()
{
    return $this->categories->firstWhere('type', 'manufacturer');
}

public function getFibersAttribute()
{
    return $this->categories->where('type', 'fibers');
}
```

**2 вариант: Relations в модели Product**

С `fibers` просто добавляем условие к нашему отношению:

```
public function fibers()
{
    return $this->categories()->where('type', 'fibers');
}
```

С `country` и `manufacture` сложнее. Здесь можно использовать `hasOneThrough` отношение (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through), чтобы получать отношение сквозь пивотную (belongsToMany) таблицу, однако здесь придётся создать пивотную модель для пивотной таблицы.

Comment: Route::get('/yarn/{category}', [CategoryController::class, 'show']); - У меня есть маршрут, который принимает один параметр и в зависимости от этого параметра мы показываем категорию. Изначально у меня и была таблица производителей, таблица стран и волокон. Как в таком случае проверить принадлежность товара? Я даже конкурс сделал на этот счёт, но никто ничего не подсказал, а это — единственное до чего я додумался.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1263554/10728

Comment: То есть, нам надо показать производителя, либо страну, либо определенное волокно и все его товары.

Comment: @РодионПоляков чем вас не устроил мой пример в прошлом вопросе?

Comment: @E_K Я Вам там ответил.

Comment: @РодионПоляков дал ответ в конкурсе. Само по себе описание задачи выглядит запутано, надеюсь правильно понял, что хотите.)